# Understanding of Example of Lİnear Combinations and Supspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ be the set of all linear combinations of $v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{n}$. Then $W$ is a subspace of $V$.

Proof. Let $y_{1},...,y_{n}$ and $x_{1},...,x_{n}$ be scalars. Then

$(x_{1}v_{1}+...+x_{n}v_{n})+(y_{1}v_{1}+...+y_{n}v_{n})$=$((x_{1}+y_{1})v_{1}+...+((x_{n}+y_{n})v_{n})$.

Thus $W$ is closed under addition. Now, let $c$ be scalar. Then,

c($(x_{1}v_{1}+...+x_{n}v_{n})$)= $(cx_{1}v_{1}+...+cx_{n}v_{n})$. i.e., $W$ is closed under multiplication.

Finally,

```
          $0=0v_{1}+...+0v_{n}$
```

i.e., $W$ has $0$. This proves that $W$ subspace of $V$.

My question is that could be $0$=$0x_{1}v_{1}+...+0x_{n}v_{n}$?

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven Yes, I'm editing.

Comment: what do you mean by $0x_{1}v_{1}+...+0x_{n}v_{n}$ ?

Comment: It wasn't be this since ($x_{1},...,x_{n}$)=($0$,...,$0$) on final statement.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, you are right.